# Python 3.8 multiprocessing: TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

We are trying to execute this piece of code using the `multiprocessing` module:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
(child, pipe) = ctx.Pipe(duplex=True)
job_process = ctx.Process(
    name="my_job",
    target=job_func,
    args=(
        child,
        server_info,
        manager,
        job_config,
        config_file,
    ),
)
job_process.start()
```

And we run into the below error in Python 3.8 that is not seen in Python 3.6:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/path/to/file.py", line 137, in includeme 
     job_process.start()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
     self._popen = self._Popen(self)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
     return Popen(process_obj)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
     super().__init__(process_obj)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
     self._launch(process_obj)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _launch
     reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 63, in dump
     ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
 TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

Is there something in the way the process is started or the arguments supplied that needs to be changed or checked? Any direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is likely a side-effect of a bigger bug in your application. [You *must* use import guards when using `multiprocessing` in `'spawn'` mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods), and failing to do so does some weird things. In particular:

1. The fork-emulation done in spawn mode will try to serialize some of the main module's state for transfer to the child process to initialize the child similarly; [`multiprocessing.Process` itself is not picklable as of Python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue46934) (though there's a patch pending to fix it), so you definitely don't want to have it anywhere it might get pickled.
2. By not using the guards, the child process's import of the main module does *all* the things the main module does, including launching a child (which itself launches a child, and so on, ad infinitum).

Both problems should be solved by using the import guard and putting everything in a `main` function called within the guard:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

# Wrapping in function avoids implicit dependencies on mutable global state
def main():
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
    (child, pipe) = ctx.Pipe(duplex=True)
    job_process = ctx.Process(
        name="my_job",
        target=job_func,
        args=(
            child,
            server_info,
            manager,
            job_config,
            config_file,
        ),
    )
    job_process.start()

# Guard ensures only the parent process tries to actually run main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I see. Two quick questions: 1) Is this related to a change from Python 3.6 to 3.8? Because we don't see this error in 3.6, and   
2) The code snippet I proved is encapsulated within an `includeme` function that is initiated by Pyramid upon server start-up, more details here: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html. Do I need to wrap further in another function?

Comment: @aaron02: 1) Yep, between 3.6 and 3.7 the `'spawn'` implementation for `multiprocessing.Process` [changed to store the `util.Finalize` object it creates](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/13e96cc596d158b98996db3fa291086ea4afecd9) so that it can be invoked early/explicitly if the newly created `close` method is called, before the `Process` is cleaned up. The finalizer doesn't otherwise need to be part of the `Process` (it works simply by being created), but once it's part of `Process`, the `weakref.ref` it hides blocks pickling.

Comment: As for 2) You don't need to wrap in another function, but you need to make sure there is an import guard *somewhere* in the flow (I'd hope Pyramid had one, but who knows?). The fact the whole server isn't falling over *probably* means you don't have a spawn bomb, but beyond that I don't know what it might be doing, or how precisely you end up trying to pickle the `Process` object (though given how much code you omitted, it could be hiding anywhere); do any of the `args` you're passing to `Process` happen to contain a `Process` themselves, perhaps indirectly?

Comment: For the record, your code as written (substituting random `int`s for the undefined variables, and a garbage `job_func` that just receives `*args` and does `print(args)`) on 3.9, and it either 1) Fails (with a surprisingly informative error) if you fail to use the import guard, or 2) Works just fine if you put everything but `job_func` and the `import`s under the import guard (whether or not it's in a function).

Comment: So your code *works* under normal usage, but my psychic debugging tells me that one of `job_func`, `server_info`, `manager`, `job_config`, or `config_file` secretly refers to a `Process` object (possibly through several layers of references), and thus can't be pickled (you could try manually pickling each of them one by one to figure out which it is). This is why [MCVE]s are important; I can't actually reproduce your problem, so all I can do is make guesses at what you might have done without showing me.

Comment: @aaron02: To be clear, [there is an open issue to fix this](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91090) (there's no reason the `Process` needs to directly store the `Finalizer`, rather than just the key it needs to *find* the finalizer if and when it's needed; the PR attached to the issue makes that change to restore picklability). If this is hurting you, absolutely comment on the issue, especially if there's no good workaround and you legit need to be able to pickle `Process`es.

Comment: ShadowRanger: thank you so much for the detailed explanation! Your links to the GH issue and PR really gives one a very good understanding of all of this!

Comment: Upon further inspection, `manager` is an instance of a class whose `__init__` method does call another method that creates a `multiprocessing.Process`. This gets initiated through another `config.include` that comes _before_ the `config.include` for this particular piece of code that caused the `weakref` error. 

And both of these need to be initiated at Pyramid server startup using `config.include`. Would you have any advice on how I can implement or check for an import guard within the `includeme` function that `config.include` calls?

Comment: @aaron02: The import guard is only needed in the main script itself; I'm guessing Pyramid script that serves as the entry point did this the correct way, so you're safe from that. If it didn't, the error messages are pretty obvious; I tried to do it on 3.9 or 3.10 and it basically dumped a big traceback that summarized with a message suggesting the need for the import guard and/or a `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` call (the latter is only needed when you are building a standalone executable from your script).

Comment: @aaron02: If you're really concerned, somewhat in your code, do `import sys`, then `print(sys.modules['__main__'])` to figure out what file actually serves as the entry point, and check that file manually. If it is doing whatever imports and initializes your modules outside a function, without an import guard, it's a problem, but it probably isn't.

Comment: I see, right now I'm stuck in a bind - I need to upgrade my systems to use Ubuntu 20.04 where Python3.8 is the default. And my Pyramid application is not starting up due to this error. I'm not sure what I should change in the code to make this work - I can't change the architecture of the code to not send the input `manager` (which may be the cause of the layered `Process`) to this `Process`.

Any advice/thoughts?

Comment: As a hacky workaround, you might be able to use [the `copyreg` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html) to try and define a reduction function for pickling `multiprocessing.util.Finalize` (the problematic component of the `Process` object), one that perhaps reduces it to a pickle that, instead of storing a `Finalize` object at all, stores information on a function that can look up a key in `multiprocessing.util._finalizer_registry`, and the key itself, so, when unpickled in a process where the finalizer exists, it can retrieve it.

Comment: You'd need some fallback for when you're deserialized in a process where the finalizer doesn't exist; the patch for this problem doesn't seem to bother to do anything about it, presumably on the assumption that you shouldn't be calling `close` on such a `Process` anyway, but if you're trying to make a valid `Process` on the other side you need to do *something* (even if it's maybe just throwing away the finalizer, so the reduction function doesn't even *try* to serialize it, it just causes a no-op function to occupy the `finalizer` attribute after deserializing so `close` becomes a no-op).